# Check if value exist in the array of objects and if it there update it

Tags: solidity

I am trying to check if the product with that id exist and if it is update quantity
Pushing all of the created struct obj to and array of objects

````
contract TheStore is Ownable {
     
    struct Store {
        uint id;
        uint quantity;
    }

    mapping(address => Store[]) public productsId;
    Store[] public store;

    
    function addProduct(uint id,  uint quantity) public {
        if(id == store.id){
     product[id].quantity +=  quantity
    }
        store.push(Store({id: id ; quantity: quantity}));
    }

    function AllProducts() public view returns (Store[] memory)
    {
        return store;
    }

         
}```
````

Answer (score 4):

With your currently defined variables, you can loop through all the existing `store` items until you've found the corresponding item, and then update it. If there's no corresponding item, you can create a new one:

```
function addProduct(uint id,  uint quantity) public {
    // loop through all `store` items until the item with the corresponding ID is found
    for (uint i; i < store.length; i++) {
        if (store[i].id == id) {
            // corresponding item found - update quantity and early return
            store[i].quantity += quantity;
            return;
        }
    }

    // no corresponding item found (the early return didn't invoke) - add the product to the store
    store.push(Store(id, quantity));
}
```

---

However, the code above is very inefficient and expensive to run gas-wise. So I'd recommend to add a mapping of existing product IDs to the `store` array indexes. Then you can simply query the mapping and get the resulting info whether the product ID exists (the value of the mapping is non-zero) or not:

```
mapping (uint => uint) productIdToArrayIndex;

function addProduct(uint id,  uint quantity) public {
    uint arrayIndex = productIdToArrayIndex[id];
    if (arrayIndex > 0) {
        // the product is stored in the `store[arrayIndex]`
        store[arrayIndex].quantity += quantity;
    }

    // no corresponding item found - add the product to the store, and add their index to the mapping
    store.push(Store(id, quantity));
    productIdToArrayIndex[id] = store.length - 1;
}
```